# Como popular múltiplos <select> “com resultados distintos”, em uma única rota app.get()?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express.js, handlebars.js

Ainda iniciante em **NodeJs** e trabalhando com **Express**, **Handlebars** e **MySQL**.

Num formulário - que no futuro será um cadastro, este possui entre outros inputs, dois `<select>` quaisquer, sendo que um deve ser preenchido com dados de uma tabela(Solicitante) e o outro `<select>` com dados de uma segunda tabela(Funcionario).

Numa mesma chamada à rota `app.get`(express), há a possibilidade de renderizar o resultado de duas consultas ao banco?

Sendo que a chamada é única e automaticamente o envio de cabeçalhos `res.send()`/`res.render()` só é permitido uma vez também.

Observação: Na tentativa de contornar isso com **SQL**, utilizei `union` na composição do `select`, mas não ajuda, pois o ***Handlebars*** não possui condicionais a nível de:

```
   {{#if tabela}}
     {{#each tabela.campo = "valor"}}
     {{/each}}
   {{/if}}
```

Nem algo similar, para que se possa popular cada `<select>` de maneira separada

Não acredito que isso seja importante, nesse caso, mas seque os códigos, tanto da chamada, quanto do trecho **HTML** com código **Handlebars**.

Observação: O código trás os dados, sendo que apenas de um dos `<select>`. Sei que o `union` não é a solução.

Trecho **NodeJs**:

```
app.get('/cad', function(req,res){
  cnx.query(' SELECT id_acadsol, st_nome_acadsol, "ACAD" as ret from tbl_academia_solicitante '+
            ' union all '+  
            ' SELECT id_func,st_nome_func,"FUNC" as ret FROM TBL_FUNCIONARIO',function(error,results){

  console.log(results);

  if(error){
    result = console.log('Erro ao obter solicitantes e responsáveis. ' + error.message);
  }
  res.render('cadsolicitacao',{
    "tbl_academia_solicitante": results
  });
})
});
```

Trecho **Handlebars**:

```
<td>
  {{#if tbl_academia_solicitante}}
  <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="sel_academia_solicitante">
  <option selected>Selecione o solicitante</option>
      {{#each tbl_academia_solicitante}}
      <option value={{id_acadsol}}>{{st_nome_acadsol}}</option>
      {{/each}}
  </select>
  {{else}}
      Nenhum resultado para a consulta (solicitante)
  {{/if}}
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como imaginei, a solução estava muito na cara!

Bastou apenas salvar os resultados das chamadas ao banco em variáveis e passar ao `render()`, no parâmetro de resultados, esses valores separadamente no objeto JavaScript.

Certeza que não precisava, mas terminei utilizando `async.waterFall`